# Как исправить ошибку композера?

Tags: php, composer

[image: c]
не работает в консоли

composer install

composer self-update

omposer install --no-dev

хотя ранее работали

использую powershell

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: указан ли путь к нему в `PATH`?

Comment: @Molod, что именно указано? не совсем понимаю

Comment: При вводе команды в командной строке, система начинает искать исполняемый файл. Ищет она его в текущим каталоге или в каталогах, которые указаны в переменной `PATH`. Чтобы посмотреть значение переменной `PATH` нужно перейти в `Система -> Дополнительные параметры системы -> Дополнительно -> Кнопка "Переменные среды..."`. Находим переменную `Path`, жмем по ней 2 раза и смотрим, есть ли там путь к composer. У меня указан такой: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`. Если нет - нужно добавить.

Comment: @Molod, есть итак

Comment: вернее, не совсем так, я правлю. А там какой то двойной путь https://sun9-86.userapi.com/impf/RPFs1GVWkGf7EInSMqTGPHWDok0mG2VOtxZaOA/q4PFii0ybAU.jpg?size=1052x121&quality=96&sign=2a8d1d3d52039dd12f0365d025709ccf&type=album

Comment: @Molod, или так и нужно? в любом случае ничего не поменялось

Comment: Сейчас еще раз глянул. Нужно смотреть переменную `Path`, которая находится в разделе `Системные переменные`. У меня там указан путь к `composer`: `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin`. Проверь, есть ли там запись. Если есть - проверь сам каталог `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin` есть ли там файлы композера?

Comment: @Molod, да, все есть